# How to access the value of Schema.sObjectField?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, schema, sobjectfield

I am new to apex coding, Can anyone please help me here?
I am working on after update trigger and I am using the below code to know what fields were updated. I got a code on StackExchange that serves my purpose.
I would like to know how I can access the value of a field from Schema.sObjectField.

```
public static Schema.sObjectField[] getChangedFields(ID recordId, Schema.sObjectField[] fieldList) {
    Schema.sObjectField[] changedFields = new list<Schema.sObjectField> ();
    SObject o1 = Trigger.oldMap.get(recordId);
    SObject o2 = Trigger.newMap.get(recordId);
    for (Schema.sObjectField field : fieldList) {
        Object v1 = o1.get(field);
        Object v2 = o2.get(field);
        if (didFieldChange(v1, v2)) {
            changedFields.add(field);
        }
    }
    return changedFields;
```

}

In the above code, "changedFields" would contain the fields that were updated.
I want to access the "value" of each field that's present in changedFields in the calling function.

How do I do that?

Thanking you in advance for the help.

Comment: v1 and v2 are the values from the field. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi , in the function that calls "getChangedFields" , I would be getting "changedFields" in return. With changedFields , for every field , I want to access the value of the field.
Can you please let me know how I can access the value of the field here ?

Comment: The get calls in this method are how you get there values. The callee can use changedFields to read the values from the record.